# How to create through relations based on enum in join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, relationships

I would like to select in simple_form `<%= f.association :organisators, collection: User.all %>` and `<%= f.association :helpers, collection: User.all %>` that source of them will be User ids stored in Participation join table with appropriate enum kind, is it a way to do it automatically with ActiveRecord relations?

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

  enum kind: [:helper, :organisator]
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :participations
  has_many :organisators, class_name: 'Participation'
  has_many :helpers, class_name: 'Participation'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :participations
end
```

When I try to save current version then it raise: `Couldn't find Participation with 'id'=1`

`event_params: {"helper_ids"=>["2"], "organisator_ids"=>["1"]}`

Answer (score 2):

> source of them will be User ids stored in Participation join table

You need to pull from the `Participation` model, *not* the `User` model:

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

  enum kind: [:helper, :organisator]
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :participations
  has_many :organisators, -> { where kind: :organisator}, class_name: 'User', through: :participations, source: :user
  has_many :helpers,      -> { where kind: :helper}, class_name: "User", through: :participations, source: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events

  has_many :participations
  has_many :participated_events, through: :participations
end
```

You've basically got a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship.

--

Thus, you *should* be able to use:

```
#app/views/events/update.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
   <%= f.association :organisators, collection: @event.organisators %>
   <%= f.association :helpers, collection: @event.helpers %>
   <%= f,submit %>
<% end %>
```

It would help if you gave some context on what you're trying to achieve. The above code should help, we may have to tweak it a little.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError at /events/new
Could not find the source association(s) "organisator" or :organisators in model Participation. Try 'has_many :organisators, :through => :participations, :source => <name>'. Is it one of user or event?` if I try to add `source: 'Participation' `then it return the same error. I would like to assign existing users to Participation model.

Comment: So you basically just want to add new users to an event?

Comment: Yes, I want to select them from list and assign as organisers or helpers.

Comment: Okay let me write an update, your original question was very confusing

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Single Table Inheritance over an enum. Keep the existing Participation model, and create two other models (helper and organiser) which will inherit from it.

Once you have implemented this, you can have two different object types which can be referenced through relationships while sharing one database model.

Take a look at this documentation:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: In this approach it returns the error `Couldn't find ParticipationOrganizer with 'id'=5 [WHERE "participations"."type" IN ('ParticipationOrganizer')]`, when I'm trying to select existing users from multiple selectbox. How to assign existing users to event.participation_organizers?